# Twitter API 2.0 Conversation_id in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, twitter, http-get

I am attempting to perform an http get request with the Twitter 2.0 API to return a conversation using the conversation_id request.

It is returning only the main tweet, but is not returning the replies to the tweet. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';


class TwitterService{
  final String twitterUrl =
      'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1176434159520075777&tweet.fields=author_id,conversation_id,created_at,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets&expansions=author_id,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets.id&user.fields=name,username'
  ;

    getPosts() async{
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(twitterUrl),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $BEARERTOKEN',
      }
      );
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      String tweetList = response.body;
      var collection = json.decode(tweetList);
      print(collection);
      return collection;

    } else {
      print('error');
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to help on the Dart side specifically (that's on my list of things to learn), but from a Twitter API perspective, the call you've made will enable you to get the conversation_id, but not the rest of the conversation.

If you look at the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id) you'll see that the request to the `/2/tweets` endpoint will let you get the ID for the conversation.

> To request the `conversation_id` for all Tweets returned on a v2
> endpoint, the `tweet.fields=conversation_id` field can be added to the
> request parameters.  The `conversation_id` field is always the Tweet ID
> of the original Tweet in the conversation reply thread.  All Tweets
> within the same reply thread, including reply threads that are created
> from earlier reply threads, will show the same `conversation_id`.

The step you are missing is the next stage, which is to use the search API to retrieve the Tweets that belong to the same thread:

> The `conversation_id` can be used as a search query parameter when
> using either recent search or as an operator within a rule for
> filtered stream.  Using the operator on its own will result in the
> entire conversation thread of Tweets being returned in either real
> time through filtered stream, or paginated in reverse chronological
> order from recent search.

Example that you should be able to adapt for Dart:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=conversation_id:1279940000004973111&tweet.fields=in_reply_to_user_id,author_id,created_at,conversation_id' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'
```

Also note that you're bounded by the recent search time period, which is 7 days of history.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I will mark this as solved. I will work on applying for an academic account to get the full conversation